# mailto in Workflow emails

Tags: designer-workflow

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I have created a workflow to send a reminder email to the owner of the item a few days before the due date.  I'm using `<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com?">Some One</a>` as part of the email.  Below is the email I'm sending.  When I receive the email the it is showing Some One as a link but when I click on it, it does not create the email with the email address.  I have created about 6 of these workflows.  On some of the workflows the mailto link works fine but on others I cannot get it to work.  I have tired copying and pasting using the code that works to a new workflow but that seem to fix this problem.  Any ideas on how to get this to work on all my workflows?  Thank you

```
<html><body><p>The following action item is assigned to you and the target date is approaching.  Please come to the next status meeting prepared to provide an update or email <a href=”mailto:someone@somewhere.com?”>Some One</a> with your update.  Thank you</p></body></html>
```

Comment: That `?` in the end of the email address seems to be what's messing it up. Also I'd check the double quotes in the `<a>` tag. Otherwise it's perfectly valid HTML that should generate a mail link just fine.

Comment: I found the ? from the w3school.com.  I first had the problem without the ? and when I was trying to figure out how to use the mailto I found it with a ?.  When I added it it worked fine.  But on other workflows with or without the ? isn't working.